# Tinder profile animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uistoryboardsegue, tinder

I am looking for library of the concept how Tinder's developers made profile animation when you click on the picture.
So I tried to watch it in slow motion, but still is not able to understand how it works.
Do they present another controller and animate scaling? Or it is temp `UIImageView` that animates and in the same time shows profile controller?

Comment: Have you figured it out? I want to know too!

Answer (score 1):

In this the concept is of two views, over lay and main view, one is swiped out and other will be shown. There is a good tutorial. look at this

https://github.com/cwRichardKim/TinderSimpleSwipeCards

Comment: Bro, can you read again the question. It doesn't say anything about cards. It  says about profile animation once you clicked on the card picture.

Comment: Moldaone Have you made Profile animation as like card picture. if you have library than please send refernence thanks